# Why transform: affects my jquery ScrollTop functions

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

```js
$(window).on('scroll load', function () {
    var hidePoint = 200;
    var stickPoint = 400;
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > stickPoint) {
        $('.sticky-header').addClass('stick');
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() > hidePoint) {
        $('.sticky-header').removeClass('stick');
    }
});
```

```css
html {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
    font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #888;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.8 !important;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.sticky-header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color:#ff8000;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}
.sticky-header.stick {
    position: fixed;
}
.filler {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="transform:translateX(-100px);">
    <div class="sticky-header">Sticky Header</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
    <div class="filler">Filler</div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to use `transform:translateX(-400px)` on the body tag.

Basically this is to create a "Push" menu, where the body slides to the left and the navigation slides into the blank space.

When I use `transform:translate` it causes all my jQuery functions that use .scrollTop() to stop working.

If I view my code using firebug and remove `style="transform:translateX(-400px)"` from the body tag, the functions start working again.

I even tried creating a "body wrapper" div right below the body tag, but it still caused the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us codes. CSS, jQuery & HTML, preferably make a JSFiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0vd2swfL/
Thanks for having a look. You'll see that if you remove the style="transform:translateX(-100px);" from the body the sticky header will work.

Comment: @CreativelyCoded This is interesting: your fiddle works fine on IE (10 and edge). That never happens! ;)